# Count results of for-if/else-statements and write it in matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to store in my code the results of the for loop (starting with "for o = 1:length(gwi)"), how often which statement("<a", ">=a & <b", ....) was used, in a matrix. I have tried to record this numerically (1-4) for the value "Liste2". But now I have the problem that I don't know how to do this for all 722 iterations (k) of the big for loop, so that at the end I get one column of a matrix for each of the 722 iterations. Also, unfortunately, the lengths of the arrays vary.

The (simplified) code follows:

```
for k = 1:722
    gwi = abs(wi);
    Liste = zeros(length(gwi),1);
    Liste2 = zeros(length(gwi),1);
    for o = 1:length(gwi)
        if gwi(o) < a;
           Liste(o) = 1;
           Liste2(o) = 1;
        elseif gwi(o) >= a & gwi(o) < b;
           Liste(o) = a / gwi(o);
           Liste2(o) = 2;
        elseif gwi(o) >= b & gwi(o) < c;
           Liste(o) =  a * ((c-gwi(o))/((c-b)*gwi(o)));
           Liste2(o) = 3;  
        else gwi(o) >= c;
           Liste(o) = 0;
           Liste2(o) = 4;   
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please simplify this into a [mcve], without context it looks like this code does a lot of stuff which is irrelevant to the actual question

Comment: I am very sorry for this. I tried to simplify it!

Comment: Apart from the  excessive use of newlines, the edit is a good improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `Liste` and `Liste2` as 2D matrices instead of arrays, so

```
% Initialise List matrices before both loops
gwi = abs(wi);
N = 722;
Liste = zeros(length(gwi),N);  % Note "N" columns
Liste2 = zeros(length(gwi),N); % Note "N" columns

for k = 1:722
    for o = 1:length(gwi)
        if condition1
            Liste(o,k) = sin(o); % some calculation for condition 1
            Liste2(o,k) = 1;     % Condition number for index (o,k)
        elseif condition2
            Liste(o,k) = exp(o); % some calculation for condition 2
            Liste2(o,k) = 2;     % Condition number for index (o,k)
        % elseif ...
        end
    end
end
```

Your result would be matrices where each column corresponds to a `k` loop, and each row corresponds to the `o` value.